# Android Studio WebView open link then grab page HTML

Tags: javascript, java, android, html, android-webview

I would like to open the 17th link on a page and then grab the entire HTML of the site to save in a string. My code is saving the HTML but not clicking on the link before. Assume it's running the command separate from the starting URL rather than one after the other.

```
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {    
    view.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){document.getElementsByTagName('a')[17].click(); window.HTMLOUT.processHTML(document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML);})()");
}



class LoadListener extends MainActivity{
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void processHTML(String html)
    {
      this.html = html;
    }
```